# Can I use "StackOverflow" in the title of my website?

Tags: discussion, legal

According to the little tooltip I get when registering an app,

> **Do not:** Use any of the full names for our websites in the name of your website or application.

By full name, do you mean "StackOverflow" or "stackoverflow.com"?

The reason I ask is because my mobile site currently displays the title "StackOverflow Mobile". I do *not* want to violate any of the rules, so I want to make sure my use is legitimate.

If the name *is* a problem, I will gladly remove it. **However**, I would be extremely grateful if you could make some sort of exception instead. I think there are certain cases (like this one) that necessitate the use of "StackOverflow" in the title - solely for the purpose of describing exactly what it is.

Anyway... thanks for reading my little request.

Oh, and if I have to change the name, suggestions would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: *If* using the full name would have been allowed, then surely it should include a space between Stack and Overflow...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We strongly believe in the value of an open platform and encouraging the healthy growth of our ecosystem. As part of that, it's important for users to be able to trust Stack Overflow and not be confused about our relationship with the many people and organizations who want to use one of our logos or trademarks.

If you’d like to make any use of our marks that is not covered by this answer, you must contact us at team@stackoverflow.com.

We understand that you want your application or product that enhances the Stack Overflow experience to be identifiable as part of the Stack Overflow ecosystem. This is important to us too, but Stack Overflow is also the name of our service and company, so we're cautious about potential confusion.

Do:

- Name your website, product, or application with something unique.
- Feel free to include language on your site explaining that your application is built on the Stack Overflow platform so people understand your product.

Don't:

- Use Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Super User, or Server Fault in the name of your website or application.
- Register a domain containing Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Super User, or Server Fault (or misspellings of those).
- Apply for a trademark with a name including Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Super User, or Server Fault (or similar variations thereof).

Do:

- Design your site with unique branding and logos.

Don't:

- Copy our look and feel, as this could create user confusion.

Answer (score 4):

- Stack Mob
- Mob Overflow
- Mobile Overflow
- Mob Flow
- Mobile Flow
- Overflobile
- Overmobile (aren't we all?)
- *SO* Mobile (yes, with the italics :) )
- Short Stack
- MoFlow

...and those are just the ones playing off of *Stack,* *Overflow,* and *Mobile.* There's gold in the creative hills once you've escaped the constraints of the obvious.

**Edit:** (more)

- Stack to Go
- GOTO Stack
- Stack Migration
- Stack in a Sack
- Stack on a Stick (logo recalls a [hobo's bindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bindle))

Comment: Thanks for the creative suggestions, but I've already picked **StackMobile**.

Comment: Is that pronounced like Batmobile?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest: **StackOverMobile**

Comment: How about StackMobile...?