# Using StackEx as a prefix for the name of my app?

Tags: discussion, legal

According to [trademark guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> [...] Including one of the terms, "Stack" or "Exchange" or "Overflow" in your product name is generally okay.

I'd like to use "StackEx" as a prefix for my app name (e.g., "StackExcavate", "StackExSave") - Is this allowed?
Also, what about replacing the "Ex" with just "X" (e.g., "StackXplore")?

- I saw [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/203/can-i-use-stackoverflow-in-the-title-of-my-website) to which [Joel suggested](https://stackapps.com/a/206/59842) to contact the team, which I did (with more questions) some time ago, but didn't get an answer (well, yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mandatory I Am Not A Lawyer prefix]

Do not overthink this - using a part of the [Stack Exchange trademark](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=87772615&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch), especially if it occurs naturally in the name of your app, is perfectly fine (unless you are trying to make a competitor service and then register it as a trademark yourself - this might get a bit more complicated).

The important part of the quote you provided is not the example, it is this part:

> Do name your application with something unique.

There are numerous prominent user organizations, applications, and scripts that are using the trademark even *in full* (the [Stack Overflow one](https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=87772598&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch)) - however, they are called sufficiently uniquely to be absolutely in the clear:

- [SOBotics](https://sobotics.org/)
- [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) (Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers)
- [SOX](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/78873) (Stack Overflow Extras)
- [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/q/4486/78873) (The Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch)

The list goes on. Some of the above explicitly add a note that they are not affiliated with Stack Exchange (e.g. SOBotic's "We are not affiliated with Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange Network."), though.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, your first two links (to tmsearch.uspto.gov) lead to some [weird page](https://imgur.com/a/DN2yu6E) - not sure if that's intentional or not.

Comment: Oh, yeah, they have a weird system of allocating resources for each visitor and then clearing them - I probably included my allocation by accident - will look in the morning, thanks!

Comment: @HeyJude - done, sorry for the confusion, seems like there is no easy way to get back to the queries when the session expires, so I relinked to TSDRs of both trademarks